# Kubernetes tls for tcp subdomain

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I am trying to create TCP entrypoint with **Traefik v2**. I have following in traefik.toml

```
[global]
      checkNewVersion = true

    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.web]
        address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.websecure]
        address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.tcp5050]
        address = ":5050"
```

and following **IngressRouteTCP**

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-external
  namespace: dev
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - tcp5050
  routes:
  - match: HostSNI(`*`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: mosquitto
      port: 5050
  tls:
```

Above one works perfectly. But can't reuse **entryPoints** **tcp5050** for any other host. I tried to make **IngressRouteTCP** specific to **HostSNI** like this

```
  apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
  kind: IngressRouteTCP
  metadata:
    name: mosquitto-external
    namespace: dev
  spec:
    entryPoints:
      - tcp5050
    routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`mosquitto.dev.domain.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
      - name: mosquitto
        port: 5050
    tls:
      passthrough: true
```

But it this doesn't work at all.

What I am missing here ?